# Can I uniquely identify a client machine in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to uniquely identify a user that has logged on my application based on his device/machine ?

In a lot of cases, the IP is enough, but in case when the client has multiple machines behind a NAT, then the same IP is exposed, so I can't tell them apart. it should have same id irrespective of browser.

for e.g. If the user logs in on his account with computer A, then log in on the same account with computer B that share the same router, I need to get id apart those two devices.

I don't know if this is possible, but it would be life saving if it is.

Comment: Can you explain the use case a bit more? What difference does it make for your app if a user hits your app from multiple devices?

Comment: This is a requirement for the application, we want to alert the user every time a new connection is made on their account based on the Ip and the machine if possible, there is a page where all connections are listed (kind of google like) and you can authorize those connections or forbid them.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this problem where I wanted to ask for Google Authenticator on sign in but only once for each device used by a user. I used a function to give me a device id based on the hostname, the MAC address, and the IP address. I know the MAC address isn't always reliable so I thought combining the data into one string might be a way round it. Our application is limited to <100 users and most of them access from the office or home so I feel it *should* be good enough.

I put the IP address function (which gets the IPV4) into a separate function as I check whether they are in office (on 192.168.*.*) or external before checking the device ID. The list of device ID's associated with a user is stored in a SQL table and checked after username/password entry but before log in is completed to decide whether to request a 2FA code.

Here's the code:

`dim thisDeviceId as String=GetClientDeviceId()`

```
public Function GetClientDeviceId() As string
    Dim mac As String = String.Empty
    For Each netInterface In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        If _
            netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType = NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 OrElse
            netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType = NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet Then
            Dim address = netInterface.GetPhysicalAddress()
            mac = BitConverter.ToString(address.GetAddressBytes())
        End If
    Next
    return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")).HostName, mac,GetClientDeviceIpAddress())
End Function

public Function GetClientDeviceIpAddress() As string
    Dim ipv4Address As String = String.Empty
    For Each currentIpAddress As IPAddress In Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())
        If currentIpAddress.AddressFamily.ToString() = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork.ToString() Then
            ipv4Address = currentIpAddress.ToString()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    return ipv4Address
End Function
```

Even though it's not bulletproof and could be improved upon it might help someone.